# Почему при нахождении верного значения в switch, не срабатывает вывод в консоль?

Tags: java

Генерируется случайный порядок букв из двух символов кириллицы, необходимо при совпадении в **case** выводить в консоль сообщение "Подбор завершен", по моим наблюдениям верное значение генерируется, но **case** не срабатывает, как правильно реализовать ?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class LearnJava {
    private static Random sRandom = new Random();
    private static char[] sAlphabet = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя".toCharArray();
    private static int sLength = sAlphabet.length;

    public static char getRandomChar() {
        return sAlphabet[sRandom.nextInt(sLength)];
    }
    static String result = String.valueOf(getRandomChar()).toLowerCase();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
                System.out.print(getRandomChar());

            }
        }
        switch (result) {
            case "ку":
                System.out.println("Подбор завершен");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Во внутреннем цикле символы должны собираться в итоговую строку, объявленную во внешнем цикле. Собирать строку можно, например, с помощью [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Статическое поле `result`, которое инициализируется один раз строкой из одного символа, в этом никак не поможет
2. Собранную строку нужно проверять на соответствие строке `"ку"` во внешнем цикле (а не вне цикла), так как она меняется на каждой итерации цикла

В итоге получается так (статическое поле `result` удалено):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    {
        sb.append(getRandomChar());
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
    if (result.equals("ку"))
        break;
}
System.out.println("i: " + i);
```

Если нужное значение так и не было сгенерировано, то в консоль выводится `1001`. Если было - от `0` до `1000`. Например, как было у меня при запуске, `399`.

Answer (score 3):

Надо что-то типа такого:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    sb.append(getRandomChar());
}
result=sb.toString();
```